# How to show overlay page using react native for iOS and android?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In my code, I am having two screens with two different `class` files. Here, I need to do screen one button click to show screen two. Screen two need to show like a `overlay` screen and if screen two button click then it should `dissolve` and back to screen one. how to achieve this?

sample screen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8kU9.png)

below code I am using for click to call another page

```
<TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ isVisible: false });
                this.props.navigation.navigate('screen2');
              }}>
```

Screen two below code

```
render () {
        const Screentwo = this.renderCarousel('test');
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <StatusBar
                      translucent={true}
                      backgroundColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'}
                      barStyle={'light-content'}
                    />
                    <ScrollView
                      style={styles.scrollview}
                      scrollEventThrottle={200}
                      directionalLockEnabled={true}
                    >
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definetly check out React Natives Modal Component https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#__docusaurus

or search something similar you like provided by the community on github for example.

Comment: button click to show another page. How to achieve this? I don't want to use navigation.

Comment: @questanswer what do u mean by u dont want to use navigation ? u dont need to in a modal u can make a modal component in a file and have your normal screen in there and if u click a button toggle the modal and show your modalscreen(component)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
 import {
          View,
          Text,
          TouchableWithoutFeedback,
          StyleSheet,
          Button,
          Modal,
          TouchableOpacity
        } from "react-native";

        function MenuTask() {
          const [isVisible, onDisapearCallBack] = useState(false);
          return (
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                backgroundColor: "orange"
              }}
            >
              <Modal animationType="fade" transparent={true} visible={isVisible}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onDisapearCallBack(false)}>
                  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)" }}>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                      <View
                        style={{
                          flex: 1,
                          justifyContent: "center",
                          alignItems: "center",
                          backgroundColor: "white",
                          marginVertical: 150,
                          marginHorizontal: 10
                        }}
                      >
                       {class 2 code}
                      </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                  </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              </Modal>
          {class 1 code}
            </View>
          );
        }

        export default MenuTask;
```

Comment: Thank you but how to call this page from another page?

Comment: please elaborate, You asked an overlay, it shows an overlay. Please ask in detail what exactly you want.

Replace "without overlay " with the main page content and other content with "Content in side overlay" , you can convert it into component too by passing props.

Comment: put the code of your second class inside <Modal>{secondClass()}</Modal>

Comment: @questanswer please upvote when you find something helpful

Comment: I have already Page1 and Page2 two different class files. Here from page1 button click then need to appear Page2 (like popup appear effect but its not popup). Page2 screen show be transparent and it should show backside screen.

Comment: @questanswer replace {class 1 code} and {class 2 code} respectively render part only and a single class will do the work. 
remember only replace view part and pull all business logic in a single file.

Comment: Please check above posted code if I use model it is showing white screen.